# reset template form in angular 6, using button outside the form

Tags: angular, forms, reset, angular6

In angular 6 I have a template form with the following markup.

`<form  (ngSubmit)="onMyFormSubmit(myForm)" #myForm="ngForm">`

Outside this form there is button that supposed to hide some elements and reset the form. The button is

`<button (cbOnSuccess)="eraseThings()"> erase</button>`

Somehow I have to access the `myForm` to reset it. My idea was to do `@ViewChild('myForm') form: ElementRef;`and then in the `eraseThings` function, I  will do

```
eraseCode(){
 this.hideTheDiv=true;
 this.myForm.reset();  
}
```

I get `Property 'myForm' does not exist on type 'AccountComponent'.`

What am I doing wrong? How can I reset the form?

Thanks

Comment: use `form.reset()`

Comment: `eraseCode` and the button are outside the form. Otherwise I could do `myForm.form.reset();`, but I cannot

Comment: They are not inside the function that handles the form submit

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `form` instead of `myForm`, so the error is correct, `myForm` does not exist in your component. So you should use `form` in your component. Also what you want is to use `NgForm` instead of `ElementRef` as we are pointing to a form reference. So your component code should look like this:

```
@ViewChild('myForm') form: NgForm;

eraseCode() {
  this.form.reset();
}
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c6vfcq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks. Great observation, but I still get `Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined`, in `this.form.reset();`. Yeah, I dont know either. What am I missing again? Does the on submit function conflicts? It is like `onMyFormSubmit(myForm: any){...`. I am lost. I hate being a newbie...

Comment: Could you please add your own code to the stackblitz and reproduce the issue there.

Comment: In my original code, the names are different, but the problem is the same. I also use the `ngxClipboard` module for copying things to clipboard. [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s3dtiy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: you have named your form `mailForm`, so it should be `@ViewChild('mailForm') form: NgForm;` and then `this.form.reset()` in component code.

Comment: @codebot there's a sample... https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-n1a46a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thats basically what I posted and I still get the same error. I dont know how to continue...

Answer (score 2):

Several alternatives here, as you're defining the form in the html, you can pass it in the function like:

```
(cbOnSuccess)="eraseThings(myForm)"
```

and in the ts:

```
eraseCode(form){
 this.hideTheDiv=true;
 form.reset();  
}
```

If you want to have the form as an attribute in the typescript for further use or modifications, take a look to reactive forms. Better than using ViewChild:
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms